# Handling Latency in Real Time Distributed Systems

Tags: real-time, distributed, latency, distributed-system

I am trying to implement a poker server. An http server forwards data packets to the backend servers which handle the state of all the poker hands. In any given hand the player to act gets 10 seconds to act (bet,fold,call,raise,etc.). If there is no response within 10 seconds the server automatically folds for them. To check that 10 seconds has passed an event list of when actions must be received is maintained. It is a priority queue ordered by time and each poker hand currently being played has an entry in the priority queue.

Consider the following scenario since the last action 9.99 seconds pass before the next action arrives at the http server. By the time the action is forwarded to the backend servers extra time passes so now a total of 10.1 seconds have passed. The backend servers will have declared the hand folded, but I would like the action to be processed since technically it arrived at the http server after 9.99 seconds. Now one solution would be to have the backends wait some extra time before declaring a hand folded to see if an action timestamped at 9.99 seconds comes. But that would result in delaying when the next person in the hand gets to act.

The goals I would like are

1. Handle actions reaching the http server at 9.99 seconds instead of folding their hand.
2. Aggressively minimize delay resulting from having to do idle waiting to "solve" problem mentioned in bullet point 1.

What are the various solutions? To experts in distributed systems is there known literature on what the trade offs are to various solutions. I would like to know the various solutions deemed acceptable by distributed systems literature. Not just various ad hocs solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe on the server side when client request arrives you could take the timestamp?
So you would take "start" and "stop" timestamps, to measure exactly 9.9s?